# Create reactphp socket for push notification in laravel

Tags: laravel, sockets, reactphp

I want to use reactphp socket for push notifications in laravel but I do not know what to do?

route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    event(new testEvent($test));
});
```

event:

```
     public $test;

    
    public function __construct($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('test.' . $this->test->id);
    }
```

channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('test.{test}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Note: I do not want to use the pusher